# Prevent hijacking a namespace to an inline namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces

Must the declaration of a namespace as `inline` be the first one, or can any (reopened) namespace be declard as `inline` at any point?

If so, is there a way to prevent someone to declare a namespace as `inline` (afterwards)?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace outer {
//inline
namespace inner {
}}

//inline namespace std {}

namespace outer {
inline
namespace inner {
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
        //::cout << "foo" << endl;
    }
}}

int main() {
    outer::foo();
}
```

---

**edit**
It seems that gcc accepts this, as I first tested only on coliru, however [clang rejects it](http://goo.gl/4TPsZt)

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7.3.1/7 shows us that it must be declared inline at the first declaration:

> If the optional initial inline keyword appears in a
>   namespace-definition for a particular namespace, that namespace is
>   declared to be an inline namespace. The inline keyword may be used on
>   an extension namespace-definition only if it was previously used on
>   the original-namespace-definition for that namespace.

Comment: Thanks! I compiled with GCC (several versions), clang shows an error